# PrintWriter not writing to the current directory

Tags: java, printwriter

I wrote a program to test union-find, quick-union and weighted quick-union algorithms, and I generate pairs of integers, and write them to a .txt file that is in the same directory using PrintWriter. To find that file in the same directory I use this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("\\unionfind\\data.txt");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

To generate random pairs of integers I use this class:

```
public class RandomIntPairGenerator {

public RandomIntPairGenerator(File file, int N){
    try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file)){

        Random rnd = new Random();
        pw.println(N);

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            int p = rnd.nextInt(N);
            int q = rnd.nextInt(N);

            pw.println(p + " " + q);
        }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }

    }
}
```

But whenever the program finishes I don't see the contents of the file at all (it's empty, or contains whatever I physically wrote to it before).

Here's the main class' code:

```
package unionfind;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UnionFind {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    oldMain();
}

static void oldMain() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = classLoader.getResource("\\unionfind\\data.txt");
    try{
        File file = new File(url.toURI());

        final int N = 25000;

        /*StopWatch stopWatchUF = new StopWatch();
        unionFind(file);
        System.out.println("Union find has taken " + stopWatchUF.getElapsed());

        StopWatch stopWatchQU = new StopWatch();
        quickUnion(file);
        System.out.println("Quick union has taken " + stopWatchQU.getElapsed());

        StopWatch stopWatchWQU = new StopWatch();
        weightedQuickUnion(file);
        System.out.println("Weighted quick union has taken " + stopWatchWQU.getElapsed());*/

        for(int i = 5000; i <= N; i += 5000){
            RandomIntPairGenerator rnd = new RandomIntPairGenerator(file, i);

            System.out.println("\n\nGenerating for " + i + "\n\n");

            StopWatch stopWatchUF = new StopWatch();
            unionFind(file);
            System.out.println("Union find has taken " + stopWatchUF.getElapsed());

            StopWatch stopWatchQU = new StopWatch();
            quickUnion(file);
            System.out.println("Quick union find has taken " + stopWatchQU.getElapsed());

            StopWatch stopWatchWQU = new StopWatch();
            weightedQuickUnion(file);
            System.out.println("Weighted quick union has taken " + stopWatchWQU.getElapsed());
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
}

static void unionFind(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    System.out.println("Union find");

    int pairsNumUF = sc.nextInt();
    UF uf = new UF(pairsNumUF);

    for(int i = 0; i < pairsNumUF; i++){
        int p = sc.nextInt();
        int q = sc.nextInt();

        if(uf.connected(p, q)){
            //System.out.println(p + " and " + q + " are already connected.");
            continue;
        }

        uf.union(p, q);
        //System.out.println("connecting " + p + " and " + q + ".");
    }

    sc.close();
}

static void quickUnion(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println("\nQuick union");

    int pairsNumQU = sc1.nextInt();
    QU qu = new QU(pairsNumQU);

    for(int i = 0; i < pairsNumQU; i++){
        int p = sc1.nextInt();
        int q = sc1.nextInt();

        if(qu.connected(p, q)){
            //System.out.println(p + " and " + q + " are already connected.");
            continue;
        }

        qu.union(p, q);
        //System.out.println("connecting " + p + " and " + q + ".");
    }

    sc1.close();
}

static void weightedQuickUnion(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file);

    System.out.println("\nWeighted quick union");

    int pairsNumWQU = sc2.nextInt();
    WQU wqu = new WQU(pairsNumWQU);

    for(int i = 0; i < pairsNumWQU; i++){
        int p = sc2.nextInt();
        int q = sc2.nextInt();

        if(wqu.connected(p, q)){
            //System.out.println(p + " and " + q + " are already connected.");
            continue;
        }

        wqu.union(p, q);
        //System.out.println("connecting " + p + " and " + q + ".");
    }

    sc2.close();
}
```

}

Which doesn't really matter, because even if I do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = classLoader.getResource("\\unionfind\\data.txt");

    try{
        File file = new File(url.toURI());
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);

        pw.println("test");

        pw.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

it still doesn't write to that file, however it does write to a file if I provide full location of it, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    //URL url = classLoader.getResource("\\unionfind\\data.txt");

    try{
        File file = new File("E:\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);

        pw.println("test");

        pw.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

So I guess it all has to do with this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

How do I make PrintWriter write to the file in the same directory then? (P.S. the program works, but it's like PrintWriter writes to that file and then cleans up after itself!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the file as a `Resource` hence you will have to look it up using `unionfind/data.txt` not `\\unionfind\\data.txt`. Also, the file that is updated would be the one that is present in the build folder along with the other class files. If the classes are in a jar file, the data.txt file in the jar will be updated.

Comment: Well, according to my tests, \\unionfind\\data.txt and unionfind/data.txt do the same thing, but my biggest confusion was the fact that if you create a file in a java project it puts it right away to both build and project folders, and if you write something in it yourself it saves changes to in both folders, however if you use PrintWriter it only saves it to the build folder, thanks for your answer!